# 405 error when from app android call Jersey Rest service

Tags: android, rest

I have a problem with an Android application the called a Rest Service implemented with Jersey: The android application send a POST request with a json parameters, ut I obtain the error 405: "Method not allowed".
This is so weird because I use the same code in another part of the app and everything runs ok.
 I searched in the web, and I tried to specify the Post in the request, but the error remain.
I hope someone could show me the error I can't see.
This is the code from the android application:

```
private class VoteContent extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String email = params[0];
        String content = params[1];
        String value = params[2];
        String comment=params[3];
        String url = Constants.baseUrl + "/content/votecontent";
        try {
            String json;
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("email", email);
            jsonObject.put("content", content);
            jsonObject.put("value", value);
            jsonObject.put("comment", comment);
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            Log.d("JSON", url);
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
           // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            out.write(json);
            out.close();
            Log.d("SERVER", "" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            Log.d("SERVER", "" + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid){
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        /*
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (aVoid==null)
         tv.setText("error");
        else
            tv.setText(aVoid);
            */
    }
}
```

and the POST:

```
@POST
@Path("/votecontent")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public Content voteContent(InputStream data) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    AppDaoImpl cd = AppDaoImpl.getInstance();
    Content risultato=null;
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println("Data Received: " + builder.toString());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        String email=json.getString("email");
        String comment=json.getString("comment");
        int content=Integer.parseInt(json.getString("content"));
        double value=Double.parseDouble(json.getString("value"));
        int id_user=cd.containsUser(email);
        cd.voteContent(id_user,content,value,comment);

        System.out.println("result OK");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
    }
    return ris;

}here
```

Comment: Double check the url

Comment: The url is correct.. I checked it, and for the other methods change the last part that in this case is /votecontent and in the other case is /newcontent :(

Comment: 405 means method not allow which basically means the url you make a request to does not implement a POST handler. Your code does have a POST handler, so it would make sense if the url was wrong

Comment: I tried: 1. If the url was wrong I have an 404 error. 2. Change the POST in GET (I know it is semantically incorrect) and I obtain again 405 error.